# How do you provide artifactory credentials from jenkins to pip install

Tags: jenkins, pip, artifactory

I've got an artifactory repository that requires credentials to download/install from. When I run `pip install ...` from the command line locally it prompts me for credentials, and I can type in my artifactory credentials just fine. I can't figure out how to run this same script on Jenkins to provide those credentials to artifactory.

It seems like Jenkins has a couple of plugins for managing credentials like https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-integrations-documentation/configuring-jenkins-artifactory-plug-in?tocId=hB8yvLfVD7HRdvBLjM9adQ but these only work from the pipeline script itself, and I can't figure out how to thread this through to pip.

I realistically have two options: (1) install from artifactory as a pip repository, or (2) install from the git repo via `git+ssh://...`. Neither option is clear to me how to pass credentials from the pipeline script to the pip install command.

How do you pass either ssh or artifactory credentials from Jenkins to `pip install`?

Answer (score 1):

Based on [pip docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/authentication/) you can use simple auth with  username-password jenkins credentials :

```
stage('Example') {
  environment { 
    PIP_CREDS = credentials('my-predefined-secret-text') 
  }
  steps {
    sh pip install https://$PIP_CREDS@pypi.company.com/simple
  }
}
```

If you use special characters - you may use .netrc file with secretFile jenkins credentalsor build it from $PIP_CREDS_USR $PIP_CREDS_PSW variables in usernams-password credentals:

```
withCredentials([file(credentialsId: 'PIP_NETRC', variable: 'my-netrc')]){
  sh "cp $my-netrc /path/to/netrc/file/location" 
}
```

you may also set .netrc path with $my-netrc variable for pip(check pip docs)

Comment: I didn't realize you could create a file in withCredentials. Thank you, I'll give this a try.

Comment: I mean with sh steps. Something like sh "touch .netrc; echo 'user: $PIP_CREDS_USR' >> .netrc; ... etc" or 
cat EOF -> something....EOF